# Why linux can't deal with hybrid graphics easily?

Tags: xubuntu, hybrid-graphics

I think the title explains the question clearly. Trying to become familiar with linux systems, so may be a noob question. However it has been a question mark in my mind since I met with linux. Why is it that hard to handle hybrid graphics architectures on linux based systems while windows doing it as easy as 1 click?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybrid graphics a set of two graphic cards with different abilities and power consumptions.

The (Old) Basic Switching Model -

This approach involves a two graphic card setup with a hardware multiplexer (MUX). It allows power save and low-end 3D rendering by using an Integrated Graphics Processor (IGP); or a major power consumption with 3D rendering performance using a Dedicated/Discrete Graphics Processor (DGP). This model makes the user choose (at boot time or at login time) within the two power/graphics profiles and is almost fixed through all the user session.

The (New) Dynamic Switching Model -

In this approach, the DGP and IGP are plugged to a framebuffer and there is no hardware multiplexer. The IGP is always on and the DGP is switched on/off when there is a need in power-save or performance-rendering. In most cases there is no way to use only the DGP and all the switching and rendering is controlled by software.

The problem with dynamic switching in Linux -

At startup, the Linux kernel starts using a video mode and setting up low-level graphic drivers which will be used by the applications. Most of the Linux distributions then use X.org to create a graphical environment. Finally, a few other softwares are launched, first a login manager and then a window manager, and so on. This hierarchical system has been designed to be used in most of cases on a single graphic card.

Therefore, the kernel has to be indicated that the graphic switching has to be done in a dynamic manner by means of a driver. However, most manufacturers like Nvidia and AMD are focused more towards the Windows side since it is more popular due to the number of games that are designed for it and the user base. It is basically a vicious cycle in which linux gets stuck.

Reference : [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/hybrid_graphics)

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Comment: thank you for your answer. as i got from here, systems which are called as muxless systems in forums, refer dynamic switching model. is there anyway to find out if my system is muxed or muxless?